# Deployed application not showing up in websphere application server 8.5 after successful deployment using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, automation, jenkins-plugins, websphere-8

I am using websphere deployer plugin to deploy application to my local WAS server. Jenkins gives a success message after deployment but the deployed application is not present on the server.

Can anyone suggest how to deal with this. I did this deployment for tomcat and that works fine for me but on WAS server it seems like file not getting correct path. I am new to WAS server. Need suggestions.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Use WebSphere admin console and check if application is visible there, and if it is started, also check SystemOut.log if it contains any errors regarding deployment and startup and add that to the question.